# Does Kagekifu mean anything?

Tags: translation

I "dreamed" up this word, and want to use this as a Product/Company/... name. Does this mean anything in Japanese? Google does turn up with a single result, but i don't understand it:

https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=%22kagekifu%22

Comment: "Secret donation"?

Answer (score 5):

First of all please let me briefly explain how Japanese writing works.
There are two phonetical alphabets which are used to write some parts of language and the largest part are Chinese characters or Kanji. Basically if something is written in any alphabet it has no meaning without context and Kanji have context within them.
So, writing anything in roman letters will not make any definite sense in Japanese even if there is such word. Only words (without context) written using Kanji have meaning.

Next, let's move to your word.

- Kageki - 過激 - excessive, radical
- Fū - 風 - wind, style
- Ha (Fa) - 派 - group, party

So, 過激派 (kagekiha) is "extremists party", 過激風 (kagekifū) is "extreme way" or "radical way".

I will leave judgment if this is a good name for a product or company to you.

Comment: Or, alternately, 影{かげ} *kage* + 寄付{きふ} *kifu*, "shadow donations".  @hakret, given the potential connotations, I don't think this would be a very good company or product name.